# test numbers and return only the decimal that have one digits on the right side

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of decimals, I want to filter it using python, and get only decimals with one digit on the right like 2.1 and 1.8, not 2.15:

```
my_list = [2.1, 2.15, 1.8, 1.995, 1.31, 2.2]
```

needed output:

```
[2.1, 1.8, 2.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiply each element by 100 and check if the last digit is zero:

```
(my_number * 100) % 10 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
condition = lambda x: (x*10)%1==0 and (x%1)!=0 # Has only 1 trailing digit
res = [num for num in my_list if condition(num)]
```

## Explanation

This program writes a condition that returns true if a number is:

- Not an integer
- Is an integer if shifted over by one

This means that it returns `True` if it has only 1 decimal place, no more, no less.

The second part simply just gets all the numbers in that list that meet that condition, i.e. having 1 decimal place.

Comment: what is num in lambda what is x in list comp

Comment: @athing I added an explanation, hope it helps

Comment: yeah but you using x in list comprehension but there is no x there. you use num in condition function in first line but it doesnt exist. did you run this exact code

Comment: @athing sorry for the late reply - changes made

Comment: still not working first line has x, num, nums all of them. what is num there? nums? they should be x

Answer (score -1):

You can use round method in both `numpy` and pure Python:

**`numpy`:**

```
import numpy as np
my_list = [2.1, 2.15, 1.8, 1.995, 1.31, 2.2]
x = np.array(my_list)
y = x[np.around(x, 1) == x]
>>> y
array([2.1, 1.8, 2.2])
>>> y.tolist()
[2.1, 1.8, 2.2]
```

**`Python`:**

```
my_list = [2.1, 2.15, 1.8, 1.995, 1.31, 2.2]
>>> [n for n in my_list if round(n, 1) == n]
[2.1, 1.8, 2.2]
```

Note that it doesn't work in general for numbers that differs by small amounts like `epsilon = np.finfo(float).eps`. For example `2.2 - epsilon` is returned to be decimal in both `numpy` and `Python`.